# Add mailchimp subscriber error: name.toUpperCase is not a function

Tags: javascript, mailchimp, axios, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to add a subscriber to my mailchimp list, but keep getting an error `TypeError: name.toUpperCase is not a function`. Here is my code, and the full output is listed below. Anyone know if there is a bug with mailchimp or am I doing something wrong?

CODE

```
const addSubscriber = function addSubscriber(user) {
  console.log('IN ADD SUBSCRIBER');
  return axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `https://${mailchimpDC}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/${mailchimpListId}/members`,
    data: {
      email_address: user.email,
      status: "subscribed",
      merge_fields: {
          FNAME: user.name.firstName,
          LNAME: user.name.lastName,
          ID: user._id,
      },
    },
    headers: `Authorization: apikey ${mailchimpAPIKey}`,
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log('res', res);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('err', err);
  })
};
```

OUTPUT

```
IN ADD SUBSCRIBER
err with mailchimp request [TypeError: name.toUpperCase is not a function]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. The authorization headers were formatted incorrectly! Authorization should be a key under the header object. I also added Content-Type. Now everything works!

```
const addSubscriber = function addSubscriber(user) {
  console.log('IN ADD SUBSCRIBER');
  return axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `https://${mailchimpDC}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/${mailchimpListId}/members`,
    data: {
      email_address: user.email,
      status: "subscribed",
      merge_fields: {
          FNAME: user.name.firstName,
          LNAME: user.name.lastName,
          ID: user._id,
      },
    },
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `apikey ${mailchimpAPIKey}`,
    },
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log('res', res);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('err with mailchimp request', err);
  })
};
```